# Memory diagnostic tool, like MemTest86

Tags: windows, hardware, memory-management, diagnostics, maintenance

Occasionally I use **[MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)** to perform a memory diagnostic, however, it is a bootable application, then I'm in search of a similar application that can run under the OS environment.

I'm aware of **[MemTest](http://hcidesign.com/memtest/)** (is not the previouslly mentioned **MemTest86**), however, it seems very simple, I would like to discover something more complete.

### Required

---

- For Windows.
- Free or paid, no matter.
- In continued development.
- Has a GUI.
- DDR2/DDR3/DDR4 support.
- Can perform x64 tests (see image below).

### Requested

---

These are all the noticeable features that **MemTest86** shows in their website, I just would like a program complete of good features like these:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that memtest needs complete control of all of the RAM and Windows itself takes control of the same, not to mention using a chunk, plus of course for all of the timing tests would be thrown out by windows.  And if your memory area under test got swapped to disk - shudder.

Comment: As @SteveBarnes said, this most likely isn't possible. Even if it were possible, the results would be incomplete/inaccurate. The only (good) way to test your RAM is to boot a computer into a RAM testing utility where said utility has full control over the RAM and can run freely, uninterrupted by an OS.

Comment: Thankyou guys for the explanations. If I delete my question without no answers, it will affect to my ban-rate?, well, no matter, I will no risk, maybe is better to let this open so people can learn from the comments above.